# why enable and disable PCIe slot when calling has_power_file()?

Tags: linux, driver, pci

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/d01e12dd3f4227f1be5d7c5bffa7b8240787bec1/drivers/pci/hotplug/pci_hotplug_core.c#L293

```
static int fs_add_slot(struct pci_slot *pci_slot)
{
    int retval = 0;

    /* Create symbolic link to the hotplug driver module */
    pci_hp_create_module_link(pci_slot);

    if (has_power_file(pci_slot)) {
        retval = sysfs_create_file(&pci_slot->kobj,
                       &hotplug_slot_attr_power.attr);
        if (retval)
            goto exit_power;
}
```

when checking this part of pci code, we can see

```
has_power_file(pci_slot)
```

will be executed. However, in

```
has_power_file():
```

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/d01e12dd3f4227f1be5d7c5bffa7b8240787bec1/drivers/pci/hotplug/pci_hotplug_core.c#L235

```
static bool has_power_file(struct pci_slot *pci_slot)
{
    struct hotplug_slot *slot = pci_slot->hotplug;

    if ((!slot) || (!slot->ops))
        return false;
    if ((slot->ops->enable_slot) ||   /////////// why force enable here ?
        (slot->ops->disable_slot) ||  ////////// why force disalbe here ?
        (slot->ops->get_power_status))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

we can see slot will be enabled and disabled, I think it changed the original slot status, isn't it?

Comment: It doesn't enable or disable anything, it just reads and checks some struct fields.

Comment: got it, the code didn't input parameter, actually, check function existed or not. but why function existed means has_power_file ?

Comment: That code is just figuring out whether it needs to create the sysfs power-control pseudo file for this device (`.../device/power`). That file is only needed if the hotplug implementation supports the `enable_slot`, `disable_slot` or `get_power_status` functions.